# Add: No hardware questions to help center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, help-center

Hardware question are generally not well received here on blender stack exchange despite that, I see a lot of people asking them. Almost all of those people are new users, that discovery has lead my to believe that these new users don't know that they are forbidden.

Now if they were to read the help center carefully, and consider whether their question fits they would see it breaks the rules, but sadly most don't. Is it possible then for someone add more information pertaining to this issue to the help center article on asking questions?

Comment: Good idea! I agree, the sooner can we update our FAQ/how to ask pages, the better. Are they mostly still at the defaults? I didn't see much content specific to blender.se last time I read through them..

Comment: @gandalf3 So how do we go about doing that...?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Post it on meta and wait for a mod to get around to it if there is no objection or if the community is in favour ;). Consider it added to my todo list. The help center is in need of an update.

Comment: @iKlsR Wouldn't it be possible to use the flag tool, so a mod sees it?

Comment: @someonewithpc These come to our inbox automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been added at https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and there are links to what the community deems off-topic at https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.